# Excel 2016 VBA 64bit - Compile error: Method or data member not found - Userform Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, compilation

I am running Excel 2016 (64 bit) and get a 'compile error: method or data member not found" which highlights the textbox name.

I can't work out why I am getting this error. 
I copied the code I had already created in another project (32bit) as this works perfectly within the 32 bit environment.

I have looked up the problems experienced because of the conflict of the 32bit Vs 64bit platforms. But I can't find a reason why the compile error as I haven't  got code anywhere else at the moment.

Would someone kindly tell me where and why there is a problem, I have the following code in the Userform named **Frm_AFI**

> ```
> Option Explicit
>    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
>    Dim wsLog As cnServiceLog ' cnServiceLog is the codename for my "Service Log" worksheet
> ```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

TXT_Date_Created.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

Dim irow As Long
Dim wsLog As cnServiceLog
Set wsLog = cnServiceLog
Dim lastRow As String


'find last data row from cnServiceLog
irow = wsLog.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
wsLog.TXTWorkOrderNo.Text = "SWC" & Year(Date) & Format(Month(Date), "00") & "-" & Format(Split(wsLog.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "-")(1) + 1, "00000")


End Sub


Sub getsettings()
    On Error Resume Next
    wb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cnServiceLog).Name
    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
        MsgBox "expected to find a Service Log worksheet, but it is missing"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cnServiceLog).Select
x = Range("A2").Value

End Sub
```

**Just a note**: This Userform must be compatible with both 32bit and 64bit excel platforms.

Thanking you in advance,

TheShyButterfly

Comment: Just to be sure. Have you checked that there is an ActiveX Textbox control named `"TXTWorkOrderNo"` on the worksheet with codename `"cnServiceLog "`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `cnServiceLog` sheet is using an ActiveX control. As per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx, if you want to stick with ActiveX controls, you're going to have to ship a 32-bit version of your workbook, and a 64-bit version that uses an available 64-bit version of the control.

Assuming you're only using the ActiveX Control *without* events, you can probably switch to a non-ActiveX Textbox control, and have a single workbook work safely in 32-bit and 64-bit hosts.

- Delete the existing ActiveX Control
- Insert a Textbox Insert..Shapes.. Text Box, and name it `TXTWorkOrderNo`

Then delete this line of VBA

```
wsLog.TXTWorkOrderNo.Text = "SWC" & Year(Date) & Format(Month(Date), "00") & "-" & Format(Split(wsLog.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "-")(1) + 1, "00000")
```

And replace with these lines

```
Dim shp As TextBox`
Set shp = wsLog.Shapes("TXTWorkOrderNo").OLEFormat.Object
shp.Text = "SWC" & Year(Date) & Format(Month(Date), "00") & "-" & Format(Split(wsLog.Cells(irow, 1).Value, "-")(1) + 1, "00000")
```

Comment: Hi ThunderFrame, thank you for your speedy reply. I am a novice at VBA,  so please excuse my ignorance, but I am a bit confused  with your reference to the ActiveX controls  - there are no options to choose from when you are adding a textbox control in the Userform, you only have the options shown. This error I have is in reference to a Userform textbox.